# Importing React Markdown NPM to Codepen returns blank page

Tags: reactjs, npm, import, codepen

I am trying to import the React Markdown NPM package into Codepen, I followed the official guide on how to import the NPM package from Codepen and it only returns a blank page. My React App is just a simple class component testing if the import works or not and so far I can't get it to work.
Anyone here has imported it before?
Thanks in advance for the replies.

Here is my codepen pen:
`enter code here`https://codepen.io/han325/pen/OJRzMeY

Comment: can you please share your codepen / code examples?

Comment: I've added the codepen pen, apologies didn't add it in the first place.